# key error: 'metric_file' using fbprophet and kernel restart

Tags: facebook-prophet

trying to reproduce Ten's tutorial on Time Series Forecasting with fbprophet (https://xang1234.github.io/prophet/). Dataset can be downloaded from https://data.gov.sg/dataset/air-passenger-arrivals-total-by-region-and-selected-country-of-embarkation

Here's my code:

```
    air=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\minri\Desktop\total-air-passenger-arrivals-by-country.csv')
    air=air[air.level_3=='China']
    air=air.drop(['level_1','level_2','level_3'],axis=1)
    air=air[(air.value!='na') & (air.value!='-')]
    air=air.rename(columns={'month':'ds','value':'y'})

    model_air=Prophet()
    model_air.fit(air)
```

below are my current versions:

pandas:  1.0.4
numpy: 1.18.5
fbprophet: 0.7.1
pystan: 2.18.0.0

INFO:numexpr.utils:NumExpr defaulting to 8 threads.
INFO:fbprophet:Disabling weekly seasonality. Run prophet with weekly_seasonality=True to override this.
INFO:fbprophet:Disabling daily seasonality. Run prophet with daily_seasonality=True to override this.
KeyError: 'metric_file'

Restarting kernel...

[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: d690f93a8e1511eb9fdc1063c874af38